# Drawing line graph for different data series in D3

Tags: d3.js, graph, line

I am drawing a line graph in d3 for three different series.
However, the line continues from one series to next, and I cannot figure out what is wrong.
In my code, I re-map from the source data to create a new array that is more friendly for line drawing. And, I create  for each data-series, and add  to each .

Could anyone tell me where my code is wrong?

Thank you!

```
//sets the domain vairable to mapColor to Variable.
mapColor.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key == "Variable"
    }));


xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([min,max])
        .range([100,1000])

var ymin = d3.min(data, function(d){
    return d.Value;
})

var ymax = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.Value;
})

yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,ymax])
    .range([1300,100])


var line2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d)
            {return xScale(d.date);
            })
        .y(function(d){
            return yScale(d.value);
            })

var cities = mapColor.domain().map(function(name) {

console.log(mapColor.domain())

var a = {name: name, values: data.map(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    console.log(d[name])
    return { date: d.Year, value: d.Value };
    })

}

return a;

  });


//create group element for each disease
var disease=  svg.selectAll(".disease")
        .data(cities)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class','disease')


disease.append('path')  
    .attr("d",function(d){
            return line2(d.values)   //d.values is array of yearly values for each    disease.
    })
    .style("stroke","blue")
    .style("stroke-width","1px")
    .style("fill","none")


}) // end of d3.csv("immune.csv")
```

data file is in CSV
Variable,Unit,Country,Year,Value,Flags
"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2001",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2002",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2003",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2004",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2005",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2006",95,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2007",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2008",94,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2009",92,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2010",92,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2011",92,

"Hepatitis B","% of children immunised","Australia","2012",92,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1980",33,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1981",40,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1982",48,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1983",55,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1984",62,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1985",68,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1986",75,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1987",81,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1988",88,

"Diphtheria, Tetanus, Pertussis","% of children immunised","Australia","1989",93,

Comment: You need to nest your data as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but could you point to the part of my code that needs to be changed? I thought my data is already nested in "Var a"

Comment: Well you're not using the inner `name` variable to extract data -- you're always returning the same values.